# Random permutations composition

Tags: group-theory, permutations, random-variables, symmetric-groups, entropy

I'm trying to prove a theorem that seems very intuitive. However, I seem to be missing a piece of the puzzle.

If:

1. $\pi$ is a random permutation ($S_n$),
2. $\pi_1, \pi_2$ - random permutations with uniform distributions over $N_1, N_2$ respectively ($N_1,N_2$ are the supports of their distributions),
3. $N_1\subset N_2\subseteq S_n$,
4. (*) missing assumption,

then entropies
$$H(\pi\circ\pi_1)\leq H(\pi\circ\pi_2).$$
I know that assumptions 1-3 are insufficient, as I've found a counterexample in $S_4$. I'm curious about your suggestions.

[Update] Application of the theorem

Thank you for very interesting contribution. Let me explain the domain of the application. Imagine I have a secret permutation $\Lambda_i\in S_n$,
$$\Lambda_i = \lambda_1\circ\lambda_2\circ\dots\circ\lambda_i,$$ of which I have some partial knowledge, namely for each $\lambda_j$ permutation I can limit the set of all possible values to $V_j$ ($|V_j| = (\frac{n}{2})!\,(\frac{n}{2})!$). The possible permutations are equally distributed. Now, I want to replace $\lambda_i$ with $\lambda_i'$ which has a substantially bigger set of possible values $V'_i$. In addition I can prove that $V_i\subset V'_i$. I would like to conclude that (assuming we treat $\lambda_j$ as random variables)
$$H(\lambda_1\circ\lambda_2\circ\dots\circ\lambda_i)\leq H(\lambda_1\circ\lambda_2\circ\dots\circ\lambda'_i).$$
To give some more information on the characteristics of $V_j$ sets I have to add that each permutation $\lambda_j$ consists of two permutations $\lambda_j = \rho_j^{(1)}\circ\rho_j^{(2)}$. I know half of the mappings in $\rho_j^{(1)}$ and $\rho_j^{(1)}$. The mappings are complementary, so I never see a complete mapping for $\lambda_j$ (image below). 
[image: knowledge about $\lambda_j$]

The revealed pattern for $\lambda'_i$ is more complex, it consists of 4 permutations. I still know half of the mappings, but I never see a complete path of length 4. However none of the sets of possible permutations seem to be a subgroup.

Comment: Please, if you still consider the given answer insufficient, clarify what you expect. Else, consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

$N_2$ is a subgroup.

In that case, $\pi \circ \pi_2$ will have uniform distribution on each coset, while the probability of each coset is the same for both $\pi \circ \pi_2$ and $\pi \circ \pi_1$.

Note that $\pi_1$ does not need to be uniform. Also, by translation invariance, the result holds equally well if $N_2$ is a coset.

(The same idea can be applied in the continuous case for compact Lie groups with the Haar measure.)

---

To understand the difficulties in further generalising the result, we introduce the concept of balance relative to a subgroup.

**Definition:** Given a subgroup $G \leq S_n$ and a random permutation $\sigma$, the balance of $\sigma$ with respect to $G$ is the entropy of the distribution of the coset of $G$ to which $\sigma$ belongs.

**Proposition:** Let $\pi$ have uniform distribution in a subgroup $G$ and $\pi_1$, $\pi_2$ be arbitrary random permutations. Then $H(\pi\circ\pi_1) > H(\pi\circ\pi_2)$ if and only if $\pi_1$ is more balanced than $\pi_2$ relative to $G$.

(We prove it by the same reasoning as above. That is, $\pi\circ\pi_i$ is uniform on each coset, so the distribution of the cosets determines the general entropy.)

With this in mind, we can see, for instance, that if $N_2$ has two even permutations and one odd, and $N_1$ has exactly one of each, then $H(\pi\circ\pi_1) > H(\pi\circ\pi_2)$ for $\pi$ uniform in $A_n$. (This gives a minimal counter-example in $S_3$, by the way.)

In general, if $N_2$ has different non-zero numbers of representatives of cosets relative to any subgroup $G$, we can find $\pi$ and $N_1 \subset N_2$ such that $H(\pi\circ\pi_1) > H(\pi\circ\pi_2)$.

Comment: Unfortunately, because of the application of the theorem I cannot assume that N_2 (or N_1) is a subgroup. N_1, N_2 are simply sets of possible values for \pi_1, \pi_2.

Comment: See the edit. Also, can you explain the application? Then I could have a better idea of what further assumptions to consider (e.g., can we restrict $\pi$? Is there any structure at all in $N_1$ and $N_2$?)

Comment: @LukN (forgot to mark you)